# Why does the SetProperty() method of INotifyPropertyChanged need a ref argument?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, ref

Considering the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged usually looks like this :

```cs
    public class Observable : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Equals(storage, value))
            {
                return;
            }

            storage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Why does the `SetProperty`method need a ref argument ? There's hardly any chance that anything else than a class field gets passed to the method, so it should alway be a reference type anyway ?

Note : I ask this question because I want to use this method with items enumerated through a `foreach` loop, which doesn't work with `ref` keyword.

Comment: Thanks though I know what the ref keyword does, my question is why is it needed in this particular case.

Comment: *" I want to use this method with items enumerated through a foreach loop"* -- can you show us that code? It doesn't sound like a great idea to me, offhand, but maybe I'm not thinking it through. P.S. your remarks about "class fields" suggest to me that may not be entirely clear about what `ref` does. It has nothing to do with reference types, and "class fields" have nothing in particular to do with reference types anyway.

Comment: I've provided an answer for why it's important - but if you need to know how to solve your particular case that uses a `foreach` loop, I suggest you ask about that in a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: The only thing `SetProperty` does with `storage` is set `storage = value`. If `storage` was not passed by reference that line of code would do nothing at all. If would update that variable locally, within the method, but that wouldn't matter because after that the variable isn't used.

Comment: My question is about why the ref keyword is important in that context, not about the loop which is another matter. I got my answer, though the way arguments are passed is still a bit unclear to me, I'll need to check that out.
When I pass a class object as parameter, won't it always be a reference to my object ?

Comment: It will be a reference, passed by value. That's different to a variable being passed by reference. See https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/parameters.html for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the great article

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intention is that you pass a *field* by reference, as well as the new value.

If this weren't a `ref` parameter, you'd be passing the *value* of the field... at which point this statement:

```
storage = value;
```

... would be pointless. That would change the value of the *parameter*, but wouldn't modify the *field* at all.

Here's a complete example to demonstrate the difference:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static string field;

    static void Main()
    {
        field = "initial value";
        Console.WriteLine($"Before Modify1: {field}");

        Modify1(field, "new value for Modify1");
        Console.WriteLine($"After Modify1: {field}");

        Modify2(ref field, "new value for Modify2");
        Console.WriteLine($"After Modify2: {field}");
    }

    static void Modify1(string storage, string value)
    {
        // This only changes the parameter
        storage = value; 
    }

    static void Modify2(ref string storage, string value)
    {
        // This changes the variable that's been passed by reference,
        // e.g. a field
        storage = value;
    }        
}
```

Output:

```
Before Modify1: initial value
After Modify1: initial value
After Modify2: new value for Modify2
```

As you can see, `Modify1` (without `ref`) didn't modify the field at all, whereas `Modify2` did.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and example !